# Unable to run Jython

Tags: java, macos, jython, robotframework

I have to have Jython/Jybot installed as part of the Robotframework swing library test automation. https://github.com/robotframework/SwingLibrary/wiki/SwingLibrary-Demo

I have followed the instructions and have included the directory containing the jar file in my PATH. However, I still get the following error:

```
davids$ jython --version

-bash: jython: command not found
```

And I get the same error with Jybot.

Here is what is in my path:

```
davids$ echo $PATH
/Users/davids/nonexistant/:/Users/davids/jython2.7.0/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

And this is what is in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Users/davids/jython2.7.0/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH=/Users/davids/jython2.7.0/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin::/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I have even ensured the 'jython2.7.0' folder and the jython.jar are rwx by all users. Not sure how the 'nonexistant' folder end up in the path. I am not sure if it was a folder that got deleted and the path automatically changed to that.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Environment is Mac OS X v10.11.3.

> UPDATE: Only when I am in the installation director jython2.7.0, and I run the following is when I can run Jython: `java -jar jython.jar'.

Comment: Instead of `/Users/davids/jython2.7.0/`, try `/Users/davids/jython2.7.0/bin`.

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to robotframework. This is just a problem with getting jython installed and configured properly. You might want to remove the python and robotframework tags.

Comment: @DavidCharles added bin in the PATH and made a 'bin' directory under jython2.7.0 and put the jython.jar in the bin, but it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You shouldn't have to make a `bin` subdirectory, it's created in the process of installing jython2.7.0.  Did you download the installer?  http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-installer/2.7.0/jython-installer-2.7.0.jar

Comment: @DavidCharles I got it to work! Turns out when I first installed Jython I picked the "Standalone" option instead of "Standard", which just created the jar file. Now I can see bin, lib and other folders in there. Thanks for your help! I can now run Jython from anywhere, but still having issues with running Jybot. Looking into that rn.

Comment: Voting to close. I wasted a minute reading the thing until I realized it was bumped to front page only because of a recent edit that added a tag... The tag might be relevant but that question is completely useless (even if we wanted to cover the mistake that is described and the resolution, that would be off-topic for SO)